# How to inject Angular 15 App into a .NET Core 6 project

Tags: angular, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

How to inject Angular 15 App into a .NET Core 6 project?

1. The Angular app exists in the same folder as the .NET Core 6

- It exists at the same same level as controllers

2. The Angular app was created separately

I am not familiar with the process and `UseSpa` keeps throwing an error in the `Program.cs` file. I installed the extension `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions` for it.

I have also copied the `index.html` from the dist folder and placed it `Layout.cshtml`, but Angular component is still not running

Comment: Hi @Kuzhapuvan, what's the error message you get? How do you inject the existed angular application?

Comment: @Rena- I am new to this. I am trying to use the solution provided in this site: https://code-maze.com/how-to-publish-angular-with-aspnet/. Please let me know your thoughts. Error only comes up when I use <app.UseSpaStaticFiles();>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! "ng build" was creating the project at a different location. When this process was mapped and files from index.html was correctly referenced, the issue was resolved,